# Realm db created as in-memory on .net

Tags: .net, realm

How can I create an in-memory Realm db on the .NET platform?  All the examples have that I've seen show an inMemoryRealmwithIdentifier param but I don't see that in the config.

This persists the data which I don't want: `var realm = Realm.GetInstance()`

Edit: Looks like this request has already been made and is still open:

https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/pull/1638

Comment: I expected it to be on the RealmConfiguration, but I don't see the option...

Comment: I wish it was that easy but then I would not have had to post here!

Comment: I recommend posting a github issue. I don't even see an open issue for it https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I've created the github issue.  Thanks.

Comment: Ahh, I'm super-blind, they really did have an issue as https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/191 and it was fixed in latest nightly (not yet released) as per changelog

Comment: Yeah, they closed my issue right away.  I'm going to test Nikola's answer.  Always appreciate all comments trying to help.

Comment: They closed it because it's already merged, just not yet released! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a different configuration class - `InMemoryConfiguration`. Use it like:

```
var config = new InMemoryConfiguration("my-identifier");
var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
```

This has been implemented but hasn't been released yet. To use it today, get the latest [nightly build](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet#nightly-builds) from myget.

Comment: Nice.. I will check that it.

Comment: Thanks this works.  I'm going to open another question but I'll just ask here too.  Is it possible to get a backup stream of the in memory database?  I'm trying to avoid touching the file system at all.